# how to center mutiple img altogether on the screen without the last pics being centered but on the left

Tags: html, responsive-design

i have some trouble finding a way to show some thumbs in the middle of the screen, especially if one resizes the window (-> responsive design).

A couple a images are displayed in the next line but then centerd...which is not a surprise at all...but how can i have the center effect (in regard to have the images displayed always in the center) 
But have the last images float left so that they have an equal beginning with the above line?) [image]

My HTML code so far looks like this (**see also he fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/Zw9Ug/)

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="de">  
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">  
        <title>Template Gallery </title>  
        <meta name="description" content="This is the content">  
    </head>  
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="inner">
                <div id ="gallery_container">
                    <!-- // TODO - hurry -->
                    <img src="http://www.hdg.de/uploads/pics/pic270-0_01.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    <img src="http://www.hdg.de/uploads/pics/pic270-0_01.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    <img src="http://www.hdg.de/uploads/pics/pic270-0_01.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    <img src="http://www.hdg.de/uploads/pics/pic270-0_01.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    <img src="http://www.hdg.de/uploads/pics/pic270-0_01.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    <img src="http://www.hdg.de/uploads/pics/pic270-0_01.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    <img src="http://www.hdg.de/uploads/pics/pic270-0_01.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    <img src="http://www.hdg.de/uploads/pics/pic270-0_01.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    <img src="http://www.hdg.de/uploads/pics/pic270-0_01.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    <img src="http://www.hdg.de/uploads/pics/pic270-0_01.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    <img src="http://www.hdg.de/uploads/pics/pic270-0_01.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    <img src="http://www.hdg.de/uploads/pics/pic270-0_01.jpg" alt="" title="" />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>  
</html>
```

css:

```
#wrapper{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:90%;
    text-align: center;
}
#inner{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
#gallery_container{
    width:auto;
    float:left;
}
#gallery_container img{
    min-height:90px;
    max-height:170px;
}
body {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your actual needs, you could either add this:

```
#gallery_container img{
   float: left;
}
```

However, the space between the border and the outermost left / outermost right image won't be the same.

Or, if you do want to achieve that effect, you could add:

```
#wrapper{
    text-align: justify;
}
```

But now the spacing between the images isn't exactly the same.

Comment: thanks for answering...these were also my alternatives...but not working the way i wanted it...isn't there any other way?

Comment: Well, you could use javascript. E.g. use justify and calculate what spacing is necessary to obtain an equal spacing.

Are your images uniform in size? That would make things easier, it might even make it easier to do all the magic with javascript and float:left.